# How to provide parameter of type String <set-?>

Tags: java, richtext, notion-api

Sorry for the beginner question. I'm using Notion API library and the `getRichText` return a `List<String>` but `setRichText` expects a parameter of type `String <set-?>`.

I have no clue what is expected here.
Obviously a `List<String>` does not work, and I have no idea how to convert the `List<String>` to `String <set-?>`.

Comment: Which Notion API library are you using?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a list to a set? You can do `new HashSet<>(myList)`. But it would help to include a *lot* more context.

Comment: I'm using com.github.seratch.

Comment: Where are you getting "`String <set-?>`"?  Give the whole error message that says that.

Comment: if a method is declared to receive a Set, "protected static final void test(Set<String> s) { }",
then the JavaDoc is "test(Set<String> s)".
Here the JavaDoc is "setRichText(String <set-?>)".
I never come to this kind of notation before!

Comment: Is there a link to the Javadoc?

Comment: I get "setRichText(String <set-?>)" from autocompletion of Eclipse. When you type the name of a variable then dot, you get the list of properties and method to select from. From the JavaDoc I guess.
The whole setter syntax being "setPlainText(String <set-?>): void - RichText".
The whole getter syntax being "getPlainText(): Sting - RichText"

Comment: This question is way to generic. What "Notion API library" are you using? Which method of which class in that library? Without this information the question and its answer is useless for other developers that face a similar problem. Voting to close because the question "Needs details or clarity".

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it just expects a String.